# pageY = -1 during mouseleave in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, mouseleave, pagey

I have such code:

```js
$(document).mouseleave(function (e) {               
       if (e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop() <= 1) {                   
            alert('Please, leave your comment!');                   
       }
});
```

It works good in all browsers excepts IE (all versions). For example, when developer tab in ie is open and you move mouse to the bottom of your screen (through this developer tab), mouseleave event fire but pageY = -1 instead of 700px in FF or Chrome or Opera. H

How can i fix it?